# error FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi I try to build an app, but I have the next error when I logout app, my app use login users, but when press logout show me this:

**error**

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from 
outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
flag. Is this really what you want?
```

**logout code**

```
public void logout() {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.clear();
   editor.apply();
   mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, LoginActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: is your `logout()` code part of activity class or some different class?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to start the activity using `mCtx` which is a non-activity context. You need to use the Activity where `logout` method reside, something like this:

```
public void logout() {
  ...
  startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
  // or use YourActivity.this instead of this
}
```

Comment: hi, when i press logout, excute this: `finish();
                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();`

Comment: you can try using `Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mCtx.startActivity(intent)` to make only login activity in the task.